# c macros in an array of a union with nested struct

Tags: c, macros

I'm struggling to find a way to use macros in the case of an array of union with a nested struct, exemplified in the code that follows.
The thing works ok in the conventional way EXAMPLE_1, as expected and also EXAMPLE_3, but some macros don't work in the EXAMPLE_2.
The snippet has 3 sections selectable by defines EXAMPLE_1/2/3 in order to facilitate the choice of each section.
According to the comments in the code, i think it illustrates my question.
Anyway if this isn't clear enough to ilustrate the issue, i'll try to be more clear.
Thank you in advance.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Tools:
// - MPLAB X 6.15
// - Compiler XC8
// - Device PIC18F47K40 (irrelevant to the case under analysis)
// This a test to understand how macros can be used in case of define an array
// of a union with a nested struct.
// The snipet as three different examples, EXAMPLE_1: convencional way, EXAMPLE_2: using
// macros that fails to compile and EXAMPLE_3  that compiles and works ok
// EXAMPLE1,2,3 switches make it easier to choose each of 
// the 3 examples.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <xc.h>

typedef unsigned int    uint;
typedef unsigned char   uchar;

// Macros de select three different ways os code
#define EXAMPLE_1             // example_1 - convencional way not using macros
#define EXAMPLE_2             // example_2 - use of macros
#define EXAMPLE_3             // example_3 - use of macros
                                   
typedef union 
{
    uchar ubuf[2];
    uint  ut16;
    struct
    {
        uchar st8lo;        // same mem_addr of ubuf[0] or ut16(lo)
        uchar st8hi;        // same mem_addr of ubuf[1] or ut16(hi)
    }sdata;
}UDATA;

#ifndef EXAMPLE_1
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // macros sction
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #define buf     ubuf[2]
    #define t16     ut16
    #define t8lo    sdata.st8lo
    #define t8hi    sdata.st8hi
#endif

UDATA data[2];      // union instantiation as an array with two dimentions

void main( void )
{
    #ifdef EXAMPLE_1
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // no macros example_1 - convencional way, works ok as expected
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        data[0].ubuf[0] = 0xa0;
        data[0].ubuf[1] = 0xa1;
        uchar a = data[0].sdata.st8lo;
        uchar b = data[0].sdata.st8hi;
        
        data[1].ubuf[0] = 0xb0;
        data[1].ubuf[1] = 0xb1;
        uchar c = data[1].sdata.st8lo;
        uchar d = data[1].sdata.st8hi;
        
        a = data[0].sdata.st8lo;    // to verify integrity of data[0] elements
        b = data[0].sdata.st8hi;
    //#endif

    #elif EXAMPLE_2
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // macros example_2 - compliler camplains
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        data[0].buf[0] = 0xa0;  // error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
        data[0].buf[1] = 0xa1;  // error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

        uchar a = data[0].t8lo;
        uchar b = data[0].t8hi;

        data[1].buf[0] = 0xb0;  // error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
        data[1].buf[1] = 0xb1;  // error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
        uchar c = data[1].t8lo;
        uchar d = data[1].t8hi;

        a = data[0].t8lo;
        b = data[0].t8hi;
    //#endif
        
    #elif EXAMPLE_3
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // macros example_3 - complile & works ok
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        data[0].ubuf[0] = 0xa0;
        data[0].ubuf[1] = 0xa1;

        uchar a = data[0].t8lo;
        uchar b = data[0].t8hi;

        uchar c = data[1].t8lo;
        uchar d = data[1].t8hi;

        a = data[0].t8lo;
        b = data[0].t8hi;
    #endif
}
```

I tried what is explained in the code snippet that is self explained by the commented code.

Comment: With this macro `#define buf ubuf[2]` it looks like you'd end up with `data[0].ubuf[2][0] = 0xa0;` after preprocessing. Is that what you were expecting? You should output the preprocessed source and take a look at it to see if what you're hoping for and what actually happens match up.

Comment: Use `gcc -E prog.c` to see the preptocessor output.

Comment: In `uchar ubuf[2]`, the name of the member being declared is (just) `ubuf`.  The `[2]` is part of its data type.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right and touched the right point.
My mistake. I reviewd tens of times and not saw the obvious.

Comment: I mean thank you all of you that replied. Issue solved!